# Video player | Change language and quality

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, jwplayer, video.js

I need to have a video player where user can change the language and quality for playing video. Like in the image below

[image]

So, for one video, I have actually 6 videos (2 qualities and 3 languages 2x3=6)

I have heard about some players like jwplayer, video.js, projector.js

With which player can I do the trick?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The JW PLayer can do this.

Here are two demos of such:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29248/sd-and-hd-qualities

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29361/multiple-subtitle-tracks

Comment: Oh, did you mean change the video language itself?

Comment: @EthanLongTail I appreciate the answer. Yes, I want to change the video language itself. But first part, I like it. Can I change the video language itself with JW Player too?

Comment: No problem. I misunderstood the 2nd question. I thought you were talking about subtitles. You would have to create a bunch of variations of the original video, in different qualities and languages, and then they would all appear in the same menu, just not two different ones, like your mock up has it designed.

Comment: I came in through the video.js tag, and did not see the jwplayer tag.  Thought you were just throwing up an advertisement for jwplayer, my mistake. Now I made it awkward... >_<

Comment: Ethan, That's correct. But how can I implement it? I have multiple videos for language and qualities.

Comment: It would be like this, but basically, you would need to make one huge list and set the labels for each language / quality together, if that makes sense - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29248/sd-and-hd-qualities, like I said before, it isn't possible like your mock up, though. I hope this helps at least.